# how to display the student name using their foreignkey

Tags: django, django-views

I have this code in my views.py

```
me = StudentsCoreValuesDescription.objects.filter(grading_Period = coreperiod)\
        .values('Marking','Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname')\
            .distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname')
```

when i tried to display it into my html

```
{% for students in me %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" value="{{students.id}}" name="student">{{students.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users.Firstname}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

nothing display into my site, and when i tried to print the **print(me)** the result is

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `__` instead of `.` in the html template? (to get the `firstname`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The name of the parameter that you are fetching and want to display in UI is different.
Try this in UI **Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname**

The parameter that you are storing and display should be same.